# Is it possible to show success message using jQuery without serialize and ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have my php to see if an user exists, and if I the user exists I echo 'sucess' and if dont exist I´ll echo 'error'.

```
$user  = isset($_POST['user']);
$pass  = md5($_POST['pass']);
$readUser = read('admins',"WHERE email= '$user' AND pass = '$pass'");
    if($readUser)
    {
        echo 'sucess';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error';   
    }
```

It is possible to show a message that I have formatted in my CSS in case of sucess, using jQuery but **without** using serialize and ajax?

I have my message formated in css:

```
.loginbox .msg{position:absolute; bottom:-66px; width:260px; font-size:15px; text-align:center; display:none;}
.loginbox .sucess{background:#000; color:#070;}
```

I have this div with a sucess message:

```
 <div class="msg"><p class="sucess">Login Sucess</p></div>
```

This is my jQuery where Im trying to show my message, **but I only want to show in case of sucess**:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
     $('.msg').empty().html('<div class="msg"><p class="sucess">Login Sucess</p></div>').fadeIn('fast');    
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nope, that's not possible (at least not easily), you either reload the page or use ajax

Comment: Why are you against using AJAX?

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your answer. So its time to start study jquery ajax! :)

Comment: `empty` is a function, you need `()`

Comment: Nat Zimmermann Im not against, its just because I need to do a work, and I never used ajax, so I was trying to do without ajax, but Im seeing that its not possible, so I´ll start study it now!